# Record audio on a mac with OBJC

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, audio-recording, qtkit

As the title says, I just want to record audio with Objective-C on a mac, not an iPhone, I just need a simple example, I've already search with core audio and QTKit, but the examples are much more complex than what I need, please, keep it simple. . . 
in deed, if you could just tell me the frameworks, classes and method needed, it will be just fine, please SIMPLE!, it would be wonderful if you include the code to play the recorded sound.

thanks in advance!

P.D: I'm sorry but i need to insist about simplicity, but sometimes people don't get the idea ;)

Comment: Take a look at this thread - see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871819/code-sample-for-capturing-audio-from-a-mac-in-cocoa-and-saving-to-file

Comment: thanks, I've already take a look at that thread before asking, but thanks anyway!

Comment: And why did you still post this question after reading that post?

Comment: After reading Apple's documentation and taking a look at some of the [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RecordAudioToFile/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003986) provided, what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Your question is missing where you want to record audio from and to, and with what format and time requirements.  There are more than one possible end points and audio formats.  Some of the complexity might be required to answer those questions.

Answer (score 1):

Having reviewed the Core Audio documentation, I'm sure you would agree that Core Audio is inherently complex, so asking for a *simple* example won't do you any good. But, if you are developing for OS X 10.7 or later you are in luck. AVAudioRecorder (of the AVFoundation framework) is very simple to use. Here's a link: [AVAudioRecorder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I am just going to write a brief example, and then post it here so others could see it before i mark this thread as answered :D!