# What is the most minimalistic way to forward audio output to audio input on macOS with Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, audio, microphone, kernel-extension

I am trying to record screen with built-in tools on macOS and the lack of audio output is frustrating. It's possible to install 3rd-party software to do the job, but their source code have lots of c++ code which feels overcomplicated for such a simple task. How hard could it be to make it in Swift?

Comment: The topic of routing and recording system audio has been covered quite a few times on SO. I'd suggest looking at Blackhole, Soundflower for the routing side and any application capable of recording audio. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443621/mac-os-x-virtual-audio-driver/18595698#18595698 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289111/get-macos-output-device-audio-buffers-in-realtime/65292316#65292316 seem relevant posts

Comment: Thx, but I am specifically interested in Swift. Soundflower is an abandoned project out-of-date. There is a working solution BackgroundMusic, but it's c++ and has too many features. I would like to see a simple solution.

Comment: Just to be clear -- I am not looking for an existing huge thingy in c++. I would like to know how to make a super simple one myself in Swift if it's possible.

Comment: I'll be very happy to eat these words in the future as I think it would be useful, but I am not confident there is a low enough level access in swift to be able to access the audio thread (s), at least to the point of being able to grab audio buffers directly. That said, even if there is, I think this question would require a pretty complex answer and is not necessarily in the spirit of SO.