How can I capture audio samples output on macOS?
I'm trying to capture audio samples from the selected output device on macOS.
I attempted to use AVAudioEngine with installTap, but I haven't had any success.
Here's a snippet of what I've tried so far:
class AudioOutputCaptureManager {
private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
private var captureCallback: (([Float]) -> Void)?

init() {
    setupAudioEngine()
}

private func setupAudioEngine() {
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    let inputFormat = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
    
    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat) { buffer, _ in
        let frameLength = Int(buffer.frameLength)
        let channels = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData, count: Int(buffer.format.channelCount))
        
        if let channelData = channels.first {
            let samples = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: channelData, count: frameLength))
            self.captureCallback?(samples)
        }
    }
}

func startCapturing(callback: @escaping ([Float]) -> Void) {
    self.captureCallback = callback
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to start AVAudioEngine: \(error)")
    }
}

func stopCapturing() {
    
}

}

AVAudioEngine allows you to capture audio from input devices, not output devices. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65292316/22147

What about ScreenCaptureKit?

Yes, you can use ScreenCaptureKit

can you help me with that? in private or here? thank you

You can do it be enabling capturesAudio on your SCStreamConfiguration object.

thank you so much, is it possible to make delay in capture audio to not make the spectrum music wave animation too fast
